# Kuzzle: Is normal to receive undefined _kuzzle_info sometimes when subscribing with js sdk 7

Tags: javascript, kuzzle

Hey sometime i get undefined `_kuzzle_info` when i subscribe to a collection.

Here is the output:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
{
  author: 'Kadmin',
  createdAt: 1591606660250,
  updatedAt: 1592384496557,
  updater: 'Kadmin'
}
undefined
undefined
undefined
{
  author: 'Kadmin',
  createdAt: 1591606660250,
  updatedAt: 1592384496557,
  updater: 'Kadmin'
}
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

as you can see this error is by group of 3.
Here is my subscribe function:

```
const subscribeData = async (jwt, devices, sock) => {
  try {
    kuzzle.jwt = jwt
    const roomId = await kuzzle.realtime.subscribe(INDEX_STATE, COLLECTION_STATE, {}, (notification) => {
      for (device of devices) {
        if (notification.result._id === device) {
          // console.log('device match!!')
          var kuzzleInfo = notification.result._source._kuzzle_info;
          console.log(kuzzleInfo);
          var items = notification.result._source;
          delete items._kuzzle_info;
          const data = {
            'id': device,
            'items': items,
            'kuzzleInfo': kuzzleInfo
          }
          sock.emit('subscribe', data);
        }
      }
    });
    sock.emit('subscribeRoomId', roomId);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('subscribeData: Err: ' + err);
    sock.emit('subscribe', {
      error: err
    })
  }

}
```

So if someone can tell me why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Normally the `_kuzzle_info` field is always set. Can you provide more context? Are you subscribed to published messages or real documents? What version is your Kuzzle backend?

Comment: Well I updated my code(without expected fix from these errors) and it stopped to give me these errors but I think I subscribed too many time in a short period of time. I subscribed to a specific collection

Comment: Kuzzle can handle more than 2000 subs/s on a single node so I doubt your error comes from too many subscriptions. Again it's weird that's `_kuzzle_info` was undefined.. If you manage to reproduce the error please let us know